# How to select a random cell from a range?

Tags: excel, vba, random

I am trying to make a random cell chooser.

I have a list of names in column A - in cells 1 to 10.

I have a button on the sheet. It should randomly select one name in the list and make it another color.
[image]

Comment: Go through the basics of vba [macros](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use RandBetween worksheet function. It will generate a number between 1 and 10 and use that to select the cell within the range `A1:A10`. The example below is using an ActiveX command button in the sheet.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10") '<==change to your sheet with data and button
        .ClearFormats
        .Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10)).Interior.Color = vbRed
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want to take advantage of `Randomize`, for seed setting, you could use the following re-write. Source of function is [wellsr.com](https://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/vba-random-number-with-rnd-and-randomize/) (minor adaptation from me).

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
        .ClearFormats
        .Cells(RndBetween(1, 10)).Interior.Color = vbRed
    End With
End Sub

Public Function RndBetween(ByVal Low, ByVal High) As Integer
   Randomize
   RndBetween = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd + Low)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go

```
Sub random()

Dim ColumnA As Long
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim HeaderRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

ColumnA = 1
HeaderRow = 1  'this is redundant but to show you if you have header then your start row is 2
StartRow = 2
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Range(Cells(StartRow , ColumnA), Cells(LastRow, ColumnA)).Interior.Color = xlNone 'remove this line if you dont need resetting


Dim randomNum As Long
randomNum = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(StartRow, LastRow)
Cells(randomNum, ColumnA).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Cells(randomNum, ColumnA).Select



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking this choosing a random cell algorithm for a time, just now I found an idea.
Didn't write code yet but my idea is something like this:

`x=randbetween(1:4)`-----if our random cell sources are located from a1 to a4
source (the location where you're going to write this random cell)= `"a1:a"&x`

Idea is just something like that for now. I didn't care to write it in exact vb codes, but I think that you can understand what I mean.
Now I got to think a way to not choosing one I choose before, maybe deleting the choosen cells and not choosing blank cells, idk but thanks for this topic-it helped me.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to:
improve text arragement, 

improve code formatting, 

See [answer]